# Size of array always returns 0 in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsurlsession

I have a problem with array in Swift.
If I have `print(self.days.count)` inside the `initialization` method, I always get correct numbers of objects in the array, `days`. However, if I use `print(self.days.count)` inside `viewDidLoad()`, I always get 0. Is there a way that I can fix it? I appreciate any help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate{
    //object array for weather
    var objectArray = [WeaObject]()
    var days = [List]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initialization {
            print("succ")
            print(self.days.count)
        }
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        print(days.count)
        //print(objectArray.count)
    }

    func initialization(completed:@escaping () -> ()){
        let jsonUrlString="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=22003&appid=c632597b1892b4d415c64ca0e9fca1f1"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let downloadDays = try JSONDecoder().decode(TestingClass.self, from: data)
                self.days = downloadDays.list
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `days` array is only populated in the completion-callback passed to `URLSession.shared.dataTask...`' which runs asynchronously and long after `viewDidLoad` returns. This is how asynchronous programming works.

Comment: I got what you said, but can you give me away to fix it?

Comment: Delete the second print line at the end of `viewDidLoad()`. It's pointless. The other `print` line inside the closure is the valid one.

Comment: The problem is I am trying to load data into TableView, so without it I cannot load data into tableView   func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        print(days.count)//It stills returns 0
        return days.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell!
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        return cell
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `reloadData()` on the table view inside your `initialization` completion block.

Update `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    initialization {
        print("succ")
        print(self.days.count)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // Do not print days.count here because days isn't updated yet
}
```

And it's best to update the data model on the main queue:

```
func initialization(completed:@escaping () -> ()){
    let jsonUrlString="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=22003&appid=c632597b1892b4d415c64ca0e9fca1f1"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let downloadDays = try JSONDecoder().decode(TestingClass.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.days = downloadDays.list
                completed()
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

You should also conform to `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSoure {
```

Comment: Thank @rmaddy, I am trying this now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry @rmaddy for late response. It works for me since I reload tableView in the method viewDidLoad()